# Connecting NodeJS app with OracleDB using SecureGateway

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, tls1.2, secure-gateway

I'm trying to connect my NodeJS app to a Oracle DB using SecureGateway but doesn't work.

I executed tests, and when I run

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var sys = require('sys');
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ping 192.168.10.8", puts);
```

for test my connection, I don't have results. So I think a don't created the connection between my app and my gateway.

When I was running in DataConnect, works normally.

I use `require('bluemix-secure-gateway')` for take the informations from my server.

The function that is used for create the tunnel are

```
const tls = require('tls');
const net = require('net');

var creations = 0;  // a running count of the number of open connections, when it becomes 0, the tunnel is closed.
var server;  // a server listening for certificate requests from the gateway server 

exports.create = function(port, options, callback) {
    if(creations == 0) {

        creations++;

        //server not currently running, create one
        server = net.createServer(function (conn) {
            connectFarside(conn, options, function(err, socket) {
                socket.pipe(conn);
                conn.pipe(socket);
            });
        });

        server.listen(port, function(){
            callback();
        });

    } else{
        //server already running
        creations++;
        callback()
    }
};

function connectFarside(conn, options, callback) {
    try {
        var socket = tls.connect(options, function() {
            callback(null, socket);
        });

        socket.on('error', function(err){
            console.log('Socket error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });

    } catch(err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};

exports.close = function(){

    creations--;
    if(creations == 0){
        // close the server if this was 
        // the only connections running on it
        server.close();
    }
}
```

The result that I have is my local net.

Comment: Are you trying to use a Node app to call Secure Gateway to reach your OracleDB? Or are you trying to have Secure Gateway establish a connection to your Node app which will then connect to OracleDB itself?

Comment: I try to call Secure Gateway to reach OracleDB. But I don't arrived to tuch local net from Oracle.

Comment: Ricardo, after establishing a TLS connection, how are you communicating with the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your application reach out to Secure Gateway, it just needs to use the cloud host:port provided by your destination.  For the connection to be accepted, you need to have the Secure Gateway Client running in a location that can access your database.

For example, if I wanted to connect to a Mongo database running on my local machine, I could create a destination with the Resource Hostname set to `localhost` and the Resource Port set to `27017`.  Once this destination is created, it will be assigned a cloud host:port (e.g., `cap-sg-prd-3.integration.ibmcloud.com:23432`).

If my application usually connects to Mongo with a connection string like `mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject`, I would change that to `mongodb://cap-sg-prd-3.integration.ibmcloud.com:23432/myproject` so the connection will be routed via Secure Gateway.

Comment: Thank you @ galen-keene! That's it. In fact, I read some tutorials but none clearly explains to me.