# Bluemix Secure Gateway - How to connect Bluemix Application?

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I've succeed to install the Bluemix Gateway service component as well as to setup the client software at a Linux system, following the "on-premises" scheme.The client is visible in the gateway and I see two green rings confirming the connectivity with a TLS tunnel.

The issue arise when connecting the Bluemix application, a REST consumer that works with HTTPS GET, retrieving data from a REST resource that is located on premises. For this purpose, I've replaced the internal host & domain name, with a simple cloud host name like "abc123" given at the registry of the destination (with no domain) plus aport number :1234, what at the application side gives an address construction of:  https://abc123:1234/mypath_to_the_app

I tried to follow the manual which tells:

*"Instructions:

In the repository where you are creating your app, when you establish a connection to your on-premises or cloud data, replace the host name and port   number with the cloud host name and port number that you were given when you created the destination."*

The error displayed at the Bluemix REST application log is "unknown host name".

My Question: 
What is the correct way to address the "Secure Gatweay"  and its destination  at the a Bluemix application executing a REST HTTPS GET request? Any further setup required to publish the Secure gateway destination address?

Comment: Does this answer help? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067868/5749279

Comment: Thanks @Galen Keene Yes, by replacing the destination address:port by the cloud host address:port I expect that there will be an end-to-end connectivity. Just found the cloud host information in the configuration display of the destination setting (under the wheel icon). Still having an issue with the ACL defined at the client side, so as soon as we fix the allow permission for the end system, I will give a feedback and confirm your answer.

Comment: Dear colleagues. Confirming. The gateway configuration is working now after correcting the ACL entry with a valid address using a host name that is reachable from the secure gateway client. At the calling Bluemix application side, we changed the the REST GET request using the cloud host addresses like: xxx-xx-xxx-x.integration.ibmcloud.com and the numerical port obtained at the boarding. The access pilot demonstrated that the GET request worked OK and returned the expected data using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice posted by @Galen Keene, we were able to circle the issue and solve the problem (see comments above).